# Why is \leftskip glue not automatically inserted?

Tags: plain-tex

TeXbook says (page 100):

> TeX has two parameters called `\leftskip` and `\rightskip` that specify glue to be inserted at the left and right of every line in a paragraph ...

Consider this example:

```
\hsize=1pt
\hfuzz=10000pt
\noindent
\leftskip=0pt
\hskip0pt
supercalifragilisticexpialidocious
\bye
```

My question is why "\leftskip" does not show up in the trace, while "\rightskip" is present, even though it is not specified explicitly.

Following is a fragment of the trace of the example:

```
..\tenrm o
..\tenrm -
..\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
.\penalty 250
.\glue(\baselineskip) 5.24405
.\hbox(6.75595+0.0)x1.0
..\tenrm c
..\tenrm i
..\tenrm o
..\tenrm u
..\tenrm s
..\penalty 10000
..\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
..\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
.\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fill
\glue(\baselineskip) 17.54861
\hbox(6.45139+0.0)x1.0, glue set - 2.00002fil
.\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil minus 1.0fil
.\tenrm 1
.\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil minus 1.0fil
prevdepth ignored
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the case of `\leftskip`, the condition

```
if left_skip<>zero_glue then
```

is written in `tex.web`, while in the case of `\rightskip`,
there is no such condition.
Therefore `\leftskip` is not shown and not inserted if it is `zero_glue`,
while `\rightskip` is shown and inserted even if it is `zero_glue`.
See egreg's comment.

For the effects of plus and minus components, see results
for the next example:

```
\nopagenumbers
{%
\rightskip=4cm\leftskip=4cm\noindent
This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test.
This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test.
This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test.
This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test.
This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test.\par
}

{%
\rightskip=4cm plus 2cm minus 3cm\leftskip=4cm\noindent
This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test.
This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test.
This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test.
This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test.
This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test.\par
}

{%
\rightskip=4cm plus 2cm minus 3cm\leftskip=4cm plus 2cm minus 3cm
\parindent=0cm \parfillskip=0cm
This is a different test. This is a different test. This is a different test.
This is a different test. This is a different test. This is a different test.
This is a different test. This is a different test. This is a different test.
This is a different test. This is a different test. This is a different test.\par
}
\bye
```

**edit:** The third paragraph illustrates the equivalent of the LaTeX command
`\centering`, and has equal stretch and shrink components on both the left
and right sides.  To maintain symmetry, this requires also that there be
zero skip at both the beginning (`\parindent`) and end (`\parfillskip`)
of the paragraph.

Comment: **plus** and **minus** components of `\leftskip` and `\rightskip` may be specified, but are they ever used, or just ignored?

Comment: the `plus` and `minus` components are definitely used in a `center` environment if what is flowed into that environment is text, and not a fixed-width box.

Comment: also in `\raggedright` macro

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Could you please give a small example, just to clarify your point? Also, how `\leftskip` and `\rightskip` are used in the process of line breaking? I couldn't find the details in TeXbook; I mean, on what stage this glue enters the process of line breaking and how the algorithms which do line breaking handle it? Add to the main answer, please.

Comment: The module is 887. I'd add that not only a zero `\leftskip` glue is not shown, but not inserted to begin with.

Comment: @Akira -- the information in egreg's comment could usefully be incorporated into your answer.  also the information requested by the op in his comment to me; i hesitate to edit your answer.

Comment: @barbara -- Please add a better example.

Comment: @Akira -- i hope this qualifies as "better".